# With Resharper's "Debug Static Method" feature, how to get it to respect binding redirects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, assembly-binding-redirect

I am attempting to use the [run configurations](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/28/run-configurations-debug-any-static-method-in-visual-studio-and-more/) from [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI04Ld-pWX1QIVkantCh05nwrqEAAYASAAEgKANfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds.ds&dclid=CIKokfyVl9UCFRA-GwodM98PaA)  to debug a static method. In summary you can right click on any static method and resharper will execute it as if it is the main program.

So I have the following method

```
public static void WireShouldWork()
{
    <snip>
}
```

it is **not important** what it does. At somepoint this calls some code that triggers the load of the `System.Reactive.Linq` library and then I get the following error.

> Could not load file or assembly  System.Reactive.Linq,
>   **Version=2.2.5.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

In the build directory I have version **2.3.0.0** of the `System.Reactive.Linq.dll` library. Normally this is not a problem as there are two files in the build directory

[image]

the dll is the file in which the above function lives and the config file holds the binding redirects. There is a binding redirect for `System.Reactive.Linq` as below.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reactive.Linq" 
                      publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
                      culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

When I use **XUnit** or run the main application the binding redirects are respected. Using the Resharper tool the binding redirects are not respected.

Is there something extra I need to do to get it to work?

### Tool Stack

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just filed a new request on YouTrack https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465613